# Formulas of propositional logic, two sets and refutation.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, artificial-intelligence

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two formulas of propositional logic and set $S_\alpha$ and $S_\beta$ be the sets of clauses representing $\neg \alpha$ and $\neg \beta$, respectively. Show that if $S_\alpha \subseteq S_\beta$ and $S_\alpha$ has a refutation, then $\beta$ must be a tautology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S_a$ has a refutation, this means that it is *unsatisfiable*.

Thus also the set $S_b$ (which includes $S_a$) is unsatisfiable.

But $S_b$ represents $\lnot \beta$ and thus $\lnot \beta$ is *unsatisfiable*.

Finally, a formula $\phi$ is a *tautology* **iff** its negation: $\lnot \phi$ is *unsatisfiable*.